# Check only date from datetime field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySql database that holds datetime in one field, in this format:

```
'2011-01-04 16:32:49'
```

How can I filter out results based on this datetime such that it shows results only from Today. basically, I only want to compare against the date part of the field.

Can I do something like this?

```
Select * from table where timestamp.date() = now().date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE(now())
```

Another alternative that will be able to use the index on `timestamp` if you have one:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE timestamp >= DATE(now())
AND timestamp < DATE(now()) + interval 1 day
```

Comment: thank you. This worked wonderfully. Will accept as soon as the time limit is over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but the column that stores the dateTime field in your database simply needs to be referenced, you should not be calling a .date() function on it.

Answer (score 1):

For mySQL, this would be:

Select * from table where DATEDIFF(NOW(),timestamp) = 0

This would give you only records in which the Date is today.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Select * from table where DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```